# Java 8 The method is ambiguous while override

Tags: java, java-8, compiler-errors, overriding, ambiguous

I have problem with the below code in Java 8. In Java 7, the code works fine but when I changed it to Java 8 it shows this error:

> The method mymethod(arg1,context,arg2) is ambiguous for the type Z.

I tried to use `AbstractContext<MyModel>` while calling the method, in Eclipse the error disappeared but while compiling it still occurs. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

```
public interface K<T extends MyModel>{
AbstractContext<T> create(T context, SomeObject arg1, SomeObject1 arg2);
}

public abstract class X {

@Override 
public AbstractContext<MyModel> create(final MyModel context,final SomeObject1 arg1,SomeObject2 arg2){
//somelogic
}
   protected String mymethod(final SomeObject arg1,
          final AbstractContext<MyModel> context, final SomeObject1 arg2){
      //some logic 
      return "test";
   }
}

public class Y extends X implements Z<MyModel>{

@Override 
public AbstractContext<MyModel> create(final MyModel context,final 
SomeObject1 arg1,SomeObject2 arg2){
//somelogic
}
   protected String mymethod(final SomeObject arg1,
           final AbstractContext<MyModel> context, final SomeObject1 arg2){
      return super.mymethod(arg1,context,arg2);
   }
}

public class Z extends Y {
   protected void somemethod(arg1,context,arg2){
     //some logic
      this.mymethod(arg1,context,arg2); 
    }//here error occurs


@Override
protected String mymethod(final SomeObject arg1,
           final AbstractContext<MyModel> context, final SomeObject1 arg2){
      //some new logic 
      return "newtest";
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing bracket in one method

Comment: Where does `arg1`, `context`, `arg2`  in method `somemethod` come from? You need these as parameters to call `mymethod` but they neither fields of `Z` nor `Y` nor `X`. It looks like as you would have to set these as parameters of `somemethod` too or to define them within `somemethod`. And if this is the case I doubt it's an error which comes with Java 8.

Comment: I've just tried this with `SomeObject arg1 = null;
            SomeObject1 arg2 = null;
            AbstractContext<MyModel> context = null;` and it compiles just fine. voting to close...

Comment: Please provide exact code.. this error is related to arguments provided with method  while calling. so you need to provide what SomeObject, SomeObject1, MyModel refers here...

Comment: I would make sure you have the latest update of Java 8.

Comment: I corrected brackets and @Override mymethod is in Z class.

Comment: I added more code to show it more clearly I hope

Comment: I'm sure that problem comes from change Java 7 to 8 because this worked earlier

Comment: I get no error here. `this.mymethod(arg1,context,arg2);` in class `Z` jumps to `protected String mymethod(final String arg1, final AbstractContext context, final Integer arg2)` in class `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

This code you provided isn't complete or it's too ambiguous ,I didn't understand what are you trying to do ?

That is your first class and it's normal (runs on jdk7,8,9,10&11)

```
public abstract class X {
   protected String mymethod(final SomeObject arg1,final 
   AbstractContext<MyModel> context,final SomeObject1 arg2){
      //some logic 
      return "test";
   }
}
```

and that is your second class :

```
public class Y extends X {
   protected String mymethod(final SomeObject arg1,final 
   AbstractContext<MyModel> context,final SomeObject1 arg2){
      return super.mymethod(arg1,context,arg2);
   }
}
```

fast tip about it Don't override a method if you don't want to change it's behavior.

now the third class :

```
public class Z extends Y {
   protected void somemethod(){
      this.mymethod(arg1,context,arg2); 
    }//here error occurs
}
```

There are some variables that you used but you didn't define -or even initialize- them So ofcourse there is an error in this line that you used them, and i tested same code using jdk7 and the same error appears.

last code which is not a class but a method that doesn't belong for any one of the classes above :

```
@Override
protected String mymethod(final SomeObject arg1,final 
   AbstractContext<MyModel> context,final SomeObject1 arg2){
      //some new logic 
      return "newtest";
   }
```

you can't create a method in java that don't belong to any class.

(Hope you to learn more about java before using different versions of jdk)

Comment: variables are initialized and they comes as somemethod arguments. And I put wrong brackets. @Override mymethod belongs to Z class.

Comment: And I can't change code in classes X and Y and interface K. I can touch only Z class